# Alert when a particular value from dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Dropdown(select) in a website that is not controlled by me.But it can be modified by javascript,html,jquery..etc(they have provided web applet for doing so)

This dropdown can be identified an ID 'Zdd_1'. All i want if the user selects "Yes" in the dropdown  then only then an alert should come. W hen the user navigates to the page. the dropdown might be Yes or some other value, but i dont care then.

I need this alert only when the state of the drop down changes from any value to "YES". I am not much into jquery and ajax, so if this can be done done simply( mean just using javascript)it would be great.

Comment: Show a bit of your code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("Zdd_1");
    dropdown.onchange = function(event){
       if(dropdown.value=="Yes"){
         alert("Your message")
       }
    }
```

or check here [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbHbL/)

Comment: simple but using normal javascript,, try to implement new technologies like jquery etc...

Comment: @ReNiShAR it simple because Sankalp told us in his question that he is new to javascript so I put in a simple way.

Answer (score 5):

It can be easly done with the help of jQuery.

```
$('#Zdd_1').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'yes')
        alert("Hi, I'm alert!");
});
```

where **Zdd_1** be the id for the select element.

If you want, of course you can use only javascript.

*Javascript:*

```
    function selectChange(element) {
        if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 'Yes')
            alert("Hi, I'm alert!");
    }
```

*Html:*

```
<select id="Zdd_1" onchange="selectChange(this)">
    <option value="Maybe">Maybe</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: firstly i am not sure val is the correct function here and secondly the op said "just javascript", i dont think jQuery is an option

Comment: OP said "But it can be modified by javascript,html,**jquery**..etc". And `val()` seems to be correct solution.

Comment: This is simply possible in javascript, then why one use jquery for this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

On change of `dropdown`, you can check whether the changed value is `"Yes"` or not, if it is Yes then **alert the text you want**.

Try this

Html

```
<select onchange="changeddl(this)">
    <option value="Maybe">Maybe</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

javascript

```
function changeddl($this)
{
    if($this.value=="Yes")
    {
        alert("Whatever you want to alert!");
    }
}
```

You can check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz2BN/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shailparas/D29BB/1/)

You can also call a `function` on `onchange` event.