# Alert when selecting some particular value from drop down in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Below are the dropdown data..

```
<select size="1" name="Test_Data">
        <option selected value="Select One">Select One</option>
        <option value="Data1">IN-Data1</option>
        <option value="Data2">IN-Data2</option>
        <option value="Data3">IN-Data3</option>
        <option value="Data4">AUS-Data4</option>
        <option value="Data5">AUS-Data5</option>
        <option value="Data6">US-Data6</option>
        <option value="Data7">US-Data7</option>
```

I want to get alert/pop up when I select the data which is start from IN in drop down list.

Comment: What have you got so far ? Show some code and where do you stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alert when a particular value from dropdown is selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109325/alert-when-a-particular-value-from-dropdown-is-selected)

Comment: You think you are the first person to ever ask how to do this on [so]? I'd imagine that question even popped up in the list as you typed the title of this question, they are so similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/mminetto/bggwnkwj/

```
var select = $('select[name="Test_Data"]');
select.on('change', function(){
    var options = select.children('option:selected');
  if(options.length > 0 && options[0].innerText.startsWith("IN")){
    alert(this.value);
    alert(options[0].innerText);
  }
});
```

Comment: Said JavaScript not jQuery, plus it's already [been covered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21109432/692942), your welcome to add your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select size="1" name="Test_Data" id="dropdown">
        <option selected value="Select One">Select One</option>
        <option value="Data1">IN-Data1</option>
        <option value="Data2">IN-Data2</option>
        <option value="Data3">IN-Data3</option>
        <option value="Data4">AUS-Data4</option>
        <option value="Data5">AUS-Data5</option>
        <option value="Data6">US-Data6</option>
        <option value="Data7">US-Data7</option>
```

in javascript

```
    <script>
        $("#dropdown").change(function(){  
            if($(this).find("option:selected").text().startsWith("IN")){    
              alert("option with IN selected =>"+$(this).find("option:selected").text());
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: As already mentioned that's not JavaScript, it's jQuery *(which is a JavaScript framework)*. This has also [been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21109432/692942) covered before, if you feel the answer adds something, go add it to that question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

**HTML**

```
<select size="1" onChange="showAlert()" id="dataCountry" name="Test_Data">
        <option selected value="Select One">Select One</option>
        <option value="Data1">IN-Data1</option>
        <option value="Data2">IN-Data2</option>
        <option value="Data3">IN-Data3</option>
        <option value="Data4">AUS-Data4</option>
        <option value="Data5">AUS-Data5</option>
        <option value="Data6">US-Data6</option>
        <option value="Data7">US-Data7</option>
 </select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function showAlert() {
var el = document.getElementById('dataCountry');  // get the index
var text = el.options[el.selectedIndex].innerHTML; // get the label
var n = text.search("IN");  //search number of IN
if(n>=0) {
alert(text);    
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: All these answers are just variations of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21109432/692942), you want to show how only alert if the value starts with a particular value then go add your answer to that question. We don't need pointless variations of the same question.